# How do I play an animation each time a widget is updated, like the default News widget?

Tags: android, animation, widget

I know that [I can't directly use animations on `RemoteViews`](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/34998e68be131cf2), but it is possible at least to add a `LayoutAnimation` - however this only plays the first time the widget is added.

I was going to accept that was the end of it, but then remembered that the default News/weather widget (at least on 2.1 up) plays an animation each time the news changes.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how this is accomplished, or does exploit a private API or do something that generally cannot be done with the SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered over on the [Android Developers group](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/0881f7992ecc3d8b).

In API Level 7 and above `ViewFlipper` is a valid `RemoteViews` view type.